# PHP CURL регистрация на сайте методом POST

Tags: php, post, curl, auth

Решил изучить curl на практике. Пытаюсь сейчас зарегистрироваться на сайте
https://www.yoox.com/myoox?newFb=False
Отправляю следующие данные

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.170");   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // пустые заголовки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);// просто отключаем проверку сертификата
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // использовать данные в post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // Автоматом идём по редиректам
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.yoox.com/ru/myoox/Register'); // Куда отправляем
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.yoox.com/ru/myoox/Register'); // Откуда пришли
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  http_build_query(['SnsId' => 0, 'SnsUserId' => '', 'AccessToken' => '', 'IsSnsConnected' => 'false', 'ReturnUrl' => '', 'Name' => 'Андрей', 'SurName' => 'Киса', 'Email' => 'qwqw@gelloiss.ru', 'Password' => 'qwqwqwqw123', 'Gender' => 'Male', 'Day' => 10, 'Month' => 10, 'Year' => 1999, 'Birth' => '1999-08-10T21:00:00.000Z', 'MobilePhone' => '+7+968+411-19-99', 'Terms[0].IsConsentGranted' => [true, 'true'], 'Terms[0].Name' => 'tos', 'Privacy' => true]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Возвращаем, но не выводим на экран результат
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

Но в результате вижу ошибку регистрации. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная проблема заключалась в том, что функция http_build_query($params) переводила 'IsSnsConnected' => false в 'IsSnsConnected=0', переделал элементы массива на 'IsSnsConnected' => 'false' и все заработало.